# Why has my generic method stopped working?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

In my project I have a factory method that loads an object that implements an interface. You pass in the class you desire and receive an instantiation of it, like so.

```
public class Factory {
    public static <E extends SomeInterface> E load( Class<E> clss ) throws Exception {
        return clss.newInstance();
    }
}
```

You could invoke it like this:

```
MyObject obj = Factory.load( MyObject.class );
```

This code works just fine in Eclipse 3.4 with Java 6u13, however today I received a new laptop and installed Eclipse 3.5 and java 6u15 and now I am getting type mismatches everywhere.

```
MyObject obj = Factory.load( MyObject.class );
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
               Type mismatch: cannot convert from SomeInterface to MyObject
```

Putting a cast before Factory on that line makes it go away and all runs well, but it makes the line a bit less clean, and I didn't need it before, so what gives?

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is to check your eclipse compile level compliance.  Make sure that it is set to 1.6, maybe it is defaulting to a previous version for some reason.

Comment: My compliance is definitely 1.6 - still no dice.

Comment: Does MyObject implement SomeInterface?

Comment: @DR Not directly, although its superclass does.

Comment: Are you sure about the above code?

Using the same setup, what I see is your Factory class failing to compile - I don't even get to the Factory.load line.

Eclipse here is complaining about 'class' being an invalid VariableDeclaratorId.  It also complains about the opening and closing braces of the class itself, but I think that's caused by the initial error.

Comment: My point in the above is that since that's wrong (you're using the reserved word 'class' as an argument name), we should look at other details, too.  Can you show us your code for "return an instance of E"?

Comment: @CPerkins: the code is perfectly valid. At least create the MyObject class ;-)

Comment: @CPerkins,@cadrian The code is something of an abbreviation, but the simple case that's up there now should work if you have a SomeInterface class kicking around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that all the code required to get this bug? I've seen something very similar in some code I've been looking at today. There was an additional parameter being passed into the equivalent of your Factory method which had a generic type as well. This was missing it's generic definition and I think was to blame for confusing the compiler.

ie, if your factory method looked something like

```
public class Factory {
    public static <E extends SomeInterface> E load( Class<E> class, Key key ) {
        // return an instance of E
    }
}
```

Where there is some Key class defined something like this

```
public class Key<Datatype> {
    ....
}
```

Giving something like this to invoke the method, note no generics on the declaration of key

```
Key key = new Key()
MyObject obj = Factory.load( MyObject.class, key );
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: This is close. I was overlooking a second parameter to my method which was a Collection<Object> (wtf!?). Turns out this was confusing the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Did you recently add a type parameter to your factory class? There's a pitfall with generic methods on raw types:

```
  public class FooFactory<UnrelatedArg> {
    public <E> E load(Class<E> c) { ... }
  }

  FooFactory<?> f; f.load(String.class); // returns String
  FooFactory    f; f.load(String.class); // returns Object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the Java compilance level. By default a project has the default level. Which you set in the Eclipse preferences. In your old installation you will have change it.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=277643